# rxjs: How can I make "from" Observable emit values after subscription?

Tags: rxjs

I've created a normal string array and steemed out an observable from it using "from"

```
import {  from } from 'rxjs';

const strArr = ['aaa', "bbb", "ccc"];

const fsa = from(strArr);
```

If I push a value to the original array before subscribing, I get that value in the data stream.

```
strArr.push("coke")

fsa.subscribe(
  x=>console.log(x) // outputs -> aaaa bbbb cccc coke
)
```

However if I push another element to the original array before the subscription, nothing happens (it doesn't behave reactively)

```
strArr.push("coke")

fsa.subscribe(
  x=>console.log(x) // outputs -> aaaa bbbb cccc coke
) 

strArr.push("pepsi") // Still outputs -> aaaa bbbb cccc coke.
```

I was expecting fsa Observable to react to every element added to the original array since it is created "from" this one.

Why causes this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: `from` only emits items in the arrays and will not emit for any array object manipulation

Comment: I see... However, If I write again the subscription piece of code below `strArr.push("pepsi")`, I see the desired result printed out ("aaaa bbbb cccc coke pepsi"). And there's still an array modification.

Comment: That’s because from is still reference to the same array that’s why u get the updated result. Array is stored as a pointer to array object in js

Comment: Thank you for your time. Could you recommmend me another or methodology, using Rsjx so that I can investigate it  to achieve what I'm trying yo do? (I'm just learning Rxjs). I don't want the job to be done for me, just  a hint.... Thank you, buddy.

Comment: I will add an answer suggest another approach

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to combine `BehaviorSubject` with javascript `Proxy` to watch for every type of changes in array

```
import {BehaviorSubject,Subject} from 'rxjs'
var originalArray = [];
const arrayChange=new BehaviorSubject(originalArray)
arrayChange.subscribe(console.log)

var arrayChangeHandler = {
  set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
    console.log('setting ' + property + ' for ' + target + ' with value ' + value);
    target[property] = value;
    // you can emit more context to the stream if you wish
    arrayChange.next(target)
    // you have to return true to accept the changes
    return true;
  }
};

var arrayProxy = new Proxy( originalArray, arrayChangeHandler );
arrayProxy.push(1)
arrayProxy.push(2)
arrayProxy.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

with an array it's not so easy, but instead of an array you can use a Subject.

The question: do you need to you an array, or is it fine to use a Subject instead?

```js
const stream$ = new ReplaySubject();
stream$.next('aaa');
stream$.next('bbb');
stream$.next('ccc');

stream$.subscribe(console.log); // [aaa bbb ccc]

stream$.next('ddd');
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // [aaa bbb ccc ddd], and the first subscription gets just 'ddd'.
```

If you want to listen to changed in an array, the best way would be to write an own Observable that overrides push method and emits into the stream. Let me know if it's the case you want and I can update the code sample.

Comment: What I wanted was to avoid to subscribe again after the next value. I had thought in this:

const strArr = ['aaa', "bbb", "ccc"];

const fsa = from(strArr);

strArr.push("coke");

fsa.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));

strArr.push("coke"); /*prints out until "coke"*/

fsa.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));

strArr.push("pepsi");

fsa.subscribe(x=>console.log(x)); /* Prints everything*/

But the block of code is the similar as yours, I mean I'm subscribing again. 

May you please provide me with the update? Thanks you so much, buddy.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I don't know how to paste code in comments so that it is legible and indented. :(

Comment: you don't need to subscribe 2nd time. it was an example. once `.next('ddd')` is called the first subscription will get `ddd`.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for what I'm trying to do. (Have the observer reacting to further changes in the array after the subscription, I hope it can help to those with similar questions:

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

const rSubject$ = new ReplaySubject();

const rSubjAsObs = rSubject$.asObservable();

// string
const str =  "I am afraid I can not do that, Dave";
//string no spaces
let strNoSpace = str.replace(/\s+/g, ''); 
//word array
let srtArr = str.split(' ');

srtArr.forEach(word=>rSubject$.next(word))

rSubjAsObs.subscribe(
  data=>console.log(data)
)

rSubject$.next("...said the good machine");
```